# Undefined reference when build a php extension

Tags: c++, zend-framework, php-extension

I'm trying to make a custom session handler for PHP.
(I didn't find a clear documentation about that. If you have a good links, I will be happy to read it ;) )

So when I try to use a zend function like `zend_string_init`
Example

```
PS_READ_FUNC(mongo)
{
    MongoClient *pMongoClient = static_cast<MongoClient*>(PS_GET_MOD_DATA());
    if(pMongoClient == nullptr)
        return FAILURE;

    std::string strSessionId = (char *)key;
    std::string strSessionData = pMongoClient->read(strSessionId);

    *val = zend_string_init(strSessionData.c_str(), strSessionData.size(), true); //generate a unreference error on __zend_malloc and _emalloc
    return SUCCESS;

}
```

To build my linker dependency list I use theses line in my makefile

```
PHP_LINKER_DEPENDENCIES =   $(shell php-config --libs)
> php-config --libs
-lcrypt -lresolv -lcrypt -lz -lpcre -lrt -lm -ldl -lnsl -lxml2 -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypt -lcrypt
```

The linking command with the error

```
g++ -L/usr/lib/php/20151012 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -o session_storage.so main.o  -lcrypt -lresolv -lcrypt -lz -lpcre -lrt -lm -ldl -lnsl -lxml2 -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypt -lcrypt -L/usr/local/lib -lsasl2 -lssl -lcrypto -lrt -lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0 -lphpcpp

session_storage.o: dans la fonction « zend_string_alloc »:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_string.h:121: référence indéfinie vers « __zend_malloc »
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_string.h:121: référence indéfinie vers « _emalloc »
```

So I don't find the library I need to link with.

*Edit about duplicate issue:*

I thinks, it's not a duplicate question. The related question is about "what is the error undefined reference ...".

I knows what is this kind of error. I just don't not find the library I need to link with. It's probably a part of zend engine but I'm not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: An undefined reference linkage error is one thing. The linker not
finding a library is an entirely different thing, and as you haven't
posted the failing linker commandline or the errors that follow
from we're in the dark as to what your problem actually is.

Comment: I have added my link command line `g++ -L/usr/lib/php/20151012 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -o session_storage.so main.o  -lcrypt -lresolv -lcrypt -lz -lpcre -lrt -lm -ldl -lnsl -lxml2 -lssl -lcrypto -lcrypt -lcrypt -L/usr/local/lib -lsasl2 -lssl -lcrypto -lrt -lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0 -lphpcpp
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I build my project like an executable but PHP require a library so.... Add `-shared` to my build option fix the problem.
Thanks for your help